# Absolute position element cannot overflow other flex items

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend, css-position

Who can I set the black box to be on top of the second box?
As you can see every brown box is 100px and the black box is 150px.
So I need the black box to fill the second half brown box too.
But I cannot figure out any way to achieve that.

[image: I have some problem with the black box. Black box m]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.contents {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: dotted 1px #c7c7c7;
  position: relative;
}

.overflowing-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="contents">
    <div class="overflowing-div"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the overflowing container is below the second `.contents`. You need to come over to the `.content`. So add `z-index: 1;` on the `.overflowing-div`. So that It can come on top of it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: dotted 1px #c7c7c7;
}

.overflowing-div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="contents">
    <div class="overflowing-div"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help